# sub a pattern in a data frame in r except for when it includes another pattern

Tags: r, design-patterns

I have a df with rows in a specific column containing the following

`temp1_01_100, temp2_01_100, temp2_02_100, s10_100, s11_100, s12_100, s21_100`

[image]

I would like to replace the "_100" with "" e.g. doing that `df$col <- sub("_100.*", "", df$col)`
but I don't want the replacement when there is the pattern "temp" no matter if it's temp1 or temp2.

the output I want is:

`temp1_01_100, temp2_01_100, temp2_02_100, s10, s11, s12, s21`

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

```
> vec
[1] "temp1_01_100" "temp2_01_100" "temp2_02_100" "s10_100"      "s11_100"      "s12_100"      "s21_100"
```

**Code**

```
vec[!grepl("temp", vec)] <- gsub("_100", "", vec[!grepl("temp", vec)])
```

**Output**

```
> vec
[1] "temp1_01_100" "temp2_01_100" "temp2_02_100" "s10"          "s11"          "s12"          "s21"
```

---

**Addendum**

For your situation, try directly with

```
df$col[!grepl("temp", df$col)] <- gsub("_100", "", df$col[!grepl("temp", df$col)])
```

Comment: seems to work with the current vector. But I have these data in different rows in a specific column in my df (where this > df$col <- sub("_100.*", "", df$col) works). I tried to adjust, but cannot make it work.

Comment: Try `df$col[!grepl("temp", df$col)] <- gsub("_100", "", df$col[!grepl("temp", df$col)])` and see whether this works

Comment: What type of data is `df$col`? It might help if you could report a sample of the entire `df`.

Comment: Considering your updated data, the proposed solution should work. Can you report the exact output you receive when you execute `df$col[!grepl("temp", df$col)] <- gsub("_100", "", df$col[!grepl("temp", df$col)]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231896/discussion-between-catinstack-and-taufi).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `gsub` like below

```
> gsub("(?<=s\\d{2})_100", "", vec, perl = TRUE)
[1] "temp1_01_100" "temp2_01_100" "temp2_02_100" "s10"          "s11"
[6] "s12"          "s21"
```

**Data**

```
vec <- c("temp1_01_100", "temp2_01_100", "temp2_02_100", "s10_100", "s11_100", "s12_100", "s21_100")
```